# Method overriding in java with same number of parameter but different return type

Tags: java, methods, return, overriding

```
class TestOverride{
    public int testVlaue(int a,int b){
        return a + b;
    }

    public float testValue(int x,int y){
        return x + y;
    }

    public float testValue(float x){
        return x;
    }
}
public class CodeTester{
    public static void main(String a[]){
        TestOverride objTest = new TestOverride();
        System.out.println(objTest.testValue(2));
        System.out.println(objTest.testValue(2,3));
    }
}
```

Why is the output as follows?

```
2.0
5.0
```

It can also take the return type int instead of float for return value 5?

Comment: And how you wanted to act? How Java have to know which function YOU want to execute? It executes the first matching. Basically, this kind of programming is wrong on many levels.

Comment: Don't bury your quesiton in comments in the code. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @RDC if you're going to edit, edit. Fix everything. Not just one character.

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to do overloading, you must change in method signature for one of these points:**

1. Parameter types.
2. Number of parameters.
3. Order of the parameters declared in the method.

**Return type** is not considered one of the method signature so if you have two methods with same name and different return type you will get compilation error, *it is not allowed to do that.*

Last,in your code you have two methods with different name so there is no compilation error and you call the method which return float

see the different in vl and va

testVlaue
  testValue

you call `System.out.println(objTest.testValue(2,3));` the second one

Comment: The qestion is about overriding, not overloading.